# How to create this beautiful Python highlighting in LaTeX with listings?

Tags: listings, python, sourcecode

I found this [beautiful Python code highlighting](https://github.com/srinadhu/RL_Pacman/blob/master/report.pdf) in a PDF today. I want it! But I don't know how to get it?

Here is what I tried:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\lstset{language=Python}

\begin{lstlisting}
# Program to display the Fibonacci sequence up to n-th term

nterms = int(input("How many terms? "))

# first two terms
n1, n2 = 0, 1
count = 0

# check if the number of terms is valid
if nterms <= 0:
   print("Please enter a positive integer")
elif nterms == 1:
   print("Fibonacci sequence upto",nterms,":")
   print(n1)
else:
   print("Fibonacci sequence:")
   while count < nterms:
       print(n1)
       nth = n1 + n2
       # update values
       n1 = n2
       n2 = nth
       count += 1
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried [minted](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Code_Highlighting_with_minted)? They tend to generate even better presentations.

Comment: @AlanXiang wow, thank you <3 ... I will use that. I have a theses to write and this is very helpful. Thank you <3

Answer (score 7):

The style you want looks very much like the one found in the overleaf guide: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/code_listing

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
 
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}
 
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}
 
\lstset{style=mystyle}
\begin{document}
\lstset{language=Python}

\begin{lstlisting}
# Program to display the Fibonacci sequence up to n-th term

nterms = int(input("How many terms? "))

# first two terms
n1, n2 = 0, 1
count = 0

# check if the number of terms is valid
if nterms <= 0:
   print("Please enter a positive integer")
elif nterms == 1:
   print("Fibonacci sequence upto",nterms,":")
   print(n1)
else:
   print("Fibonacci sequence:")
   while count < nterms:
       print(n1)
       nth = n1 + n2
       # update values
       n1 = n2
       n2 = nth
       count += 1
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]